# Word: how to split large images over pages automatically?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm writing a report and a lot of the images are fairly big, and when an image is too big to fit on a page, it starts a whole new page.  I was wondering if it is possible to have word split images automatically over page breaks so you don't have big white space everywhere.

Comment: I think so... what version of word are you using?  What operating system?

Comment: Word 2010, Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into this problem. The solution that worked for me was to insert the same image twice—one after another—and then crop each one independently to fit the page as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Not as far as I know.

You can scale the images in Word to ensure they fit on a single page, but the default it to import the image at 1:1.

If the image is truly too big to fit on a single page then you'll need to split it in a paint package (Paint.NET for example) and insert it in sections.

Comment: Ah, I guess this is the answer I have to live with.  The problem with manually splitting images is that if I add things later on, the splitting would have to be adjusted.  Anyway, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @sooprise - I could be wrong :) However, I am assuming that you've tried various things before asking here.